# train GAN generator gradient is always 0 and Discriminator is doing well

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

when i try to train gan the gradient  alway send me a mess
and i ues this code to see gradient  gradient  but it 0

```
print(self.ganout.ganout1[0].weight.grad)
```

[gradient img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyRkp.png)

this is all code
what wrong i do

```
import os
import time
from collections import OrderedDict
# from pl_bolts.models.gans import DCGAN
import numpy
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
import pytorch_lightning as pyl
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.autograd._functions import tensor
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import cv2
from PIL import Image
class cc_block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride):
        super().__init__()
        self.inn=0
        self.convv =nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride)

    def forward(self, x):
        self.inn=x
        aa =self.convv(x)
        cc = torch.add(self.inn, aa)

        # b = self.ganj2(a.view(3*22*17*4))
        return cc

class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_chans,n_chans1):
        super(ResBlock, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(n_chans, n_chans1,
                              kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2),
                              bias=False)
        self.batch_norm = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=n_chans)  # <5>
        torch.nn.init.kaiming_normal_(self.conv.weight,
                                      nonlinearity='relu')  # <6>
        torch.nn.init.constant_(self.batch_norm.weight, 0.5)  # <7>
        torch.nn.init.zeros_(self.batch_norm.bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv(x)
        out = self.batch_norm(out)
        out = torch.relu(out)
        return out + x

class jian(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super().__init__()
        self.ganj = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=300, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)),
                                  nn.BatchNorm2d(300), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
                                  nn.Conv2d(in_channels=300, out_channels=300, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)),
                                  # ResBlock(300, 300,),
                                  nn.BatchNorm2d(300), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
                                  nn.Conv2d(in_channels=300, out_channels=3, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)),
                                  nn.LeakyReLU(0.2))  # 22 17

        self.ganj2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3 * 22 * 17, 1), nn.Sigmoid())
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(),lr=0.00001)

    def forward(self, x):
        a = self.ganj(x)
        b = self.ganj2(a.view(3 * 22 * 17))
        # b = self.ganj2(a.view(3*22*17*4))
        return b
class grent(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()
        self.ganout1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(100, 6 * 22 * 17), nn.SELU())
        # self.ganout1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(1, 3 * 22 * 17), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),nn.Linear(3 * 22 * 17, 3 * 50 * 30), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),nn.Linear( 3 * 50 * 30,  3 * 150 * 50), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),nn.Linear( 3 * 150 * 100,  3 * 200 * 150), nn.SELU(),nn.Linear( 3 * 200 * 150,  3 * 218 * 178), nn.Sigmoid())
        # self.ganout1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10, 3 * 218 ), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),nn.Linear(3 * 218, 3000 ), nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),nn.Linear(3000 , 3 * 218 * 178),nn.Sigmoid())

        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=0.00001)


        # self.ganout = nn.Sequential(
        #     nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=400, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)), nn.BatchNorm2d(400),
        #     nn.SELU(), nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=400, out_channels=400, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)),
        #     nn.BatchNorm2d(400), nn.SELU(),
        #     nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=400, out_channels=3, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)),
        #     nn.Sigmoid())
        self.ganout = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=400, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)),
            nn.SELU(), nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=400, out_channels=400, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)),
            nn.SELU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=400, out_channels=3, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(2, 2)),
            nn.Sigmoid())
    def forward(self, x):
        a = self.ganout1(x)

        # a =a.view((1,3 , 218, 178))
        b = self.ganout(a.view((1,6 , 22, 17)))
        # b = self.ganj2(a.view(3*22*17*4))
        return b


class main_modle(pyl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super().__init__()

        self.ganout = grent()

        self.ganj = jian()




    def forward(self, inputs):
        a =self.ganout(inputs)

        # b = self.ganj2(a.view(3*22*17*4))
        return a


    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = jian().optimizer
        # optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.ganj.parameters(),lr=0.00001)
        # optimizer2 = torch.optim.Adam(self.ganout.parameters(),lr=0.0003 )
        # optimizer2 = torch.optim.Adam(self.ganout.parameters(), lr=0.0003)
        optimizer2 = grent().optimizer
        return optimizer2,optimizer

        # return optimizer,

    def adversarial_loss(self, y_hat, y):
        return F.binary_cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx,optimizer_idx):
    # def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx,):
    #     x , y =batch
        self.loss_function = nn.BCELoss()

        self.zero_grad()



        x = batch[0]
        if optimizer_idx == 1:
            if batch_idx%1==0:
                outt=self.ganj(x)
                if torch.isnan(outt).any():
                    outt =Variable(torch.tensor([1.0]),requires_grad=True).type_as(x)
                aa = torch.as_tensor(torch.Tensor([1.0])).type_as(x)
                # realloss =self.loss_function(outt,aa)
                realloss=self.adversarial_loss(outt,aa)
                aaas = torch.round(self.forward(torch.randn([100]).type_as(x) ).detach() *255)
                outt2 = self.ganj(aaas)
                if torch.isnan(outt2).any():
                    outt2 =Variable(torch.tensor([0.0]),requires_grad=True).type_as(x)
                aa2 = torch.as_tensor(torch.Tensor([0.0])).type_as(x)
                # fuckloss = self.loss_function(outt2, aa2)
                fuckloss = self.adversarial_loss(outt2, aa2)

                mainloss = (realloss +fuckloss) /2
                csdfsd =0
                tqdm_dict = {"d_loss": mainloss}
                output = OrderedDict({"loss": mainloss, "progress_bar": tqdm_dict, "log": tqdm_dict})
                # return output
                self.log_dict(tqdm_dict)
                return  mainloss
            # else:
            #
            #     mainloss = fuckloss
            #     tqdm_dict = {"d_loss": mainloss}
            #     csdfsd = 0
            #     output = OrderedDict({"loss": mainloss, "progress_bar": tqdm_dict, "log": tqdm_dict})
            #     return output
        if optimizer_idx == 0:
            self.loss_function2 = nn.MSELoss()

            outt2 = self.ganj(torch.round(self.ganout(torch.randn([100]).type_as(x))*255))
            if torch.isnan(outt2).any():
                outt2 =Variable(torch.tensor([0.0]),requires_grad=True).type_as(x)

            asds =torch.Tensor([1.0]).type_as(x)
            # losss = self.loss_function2(outt2,asds)
            losss = self.adversarial_loss(outt2, torch.Tensor([1.0]).type_as(x))
            csdfsd = 0

            if batch_idx%100 ==0:
                aaas = torch.round(self.ganout(torch.randn([100]).type_as(x)) * 255)
                print(self.ganout.state_dict().keys())
                # print(self.ganout.ganout1[0].weight)
                print(self.ganout.ganout1[0].weight.grad)
                img_1 = aaas[0].cpu().detach().numpy()
                img_1 = img_1.astype('uint8')
                img_1 = np.transpose(img_1, (1, 2, 0))  # 将通道数移到最后
                cv2.imwrite('./114/'+str(batch_idx)+'.png',img_1)
            # torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
            # losss.backward(retain_graph=True)
            # a =self.configure_optimizers()
            # a[0].step()
            tqdm_dict = {"g_loss": losss}
            output = OrderedDict({"loss": losss, "progress_bar": tqdm_dict, "log": tqdm_dict})
            # return output
            self.log_dict(tqdm_dict)
            return losss
            #
            # return losss








        # a =x.shape
        # c =self.forward(x)
        # # print(c.shape)
        # # print (a)
        aaaaasss =0


        # return self.loss_function(c,aa)
    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        pass


class dataset2(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csc_file):
        # self.data_df= pd.read_csv(csc_file,header=None)
        self.filll = os.listdir(csc_file)
        # print( self.filll)
        self.num =len(self.filll)
        if csc_file[-1] == '/':
            self.path = csc_file
        else:
            self.path = csc_file + '/'

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num
        # return self.num + 212000

    def __getitem__(self, index):

        if index <= self.num:
        # if 0:
            filllsd = self.filll[index]

            img = cv2.imread(self.path + filllsd)
            image1 = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            imgg = torch.FloatTensor(img)
            img = numpy.transpose(imgg, (2, 0, 1))
            # input = torch.from_numpy(img)
            input1 = torch.FloatTensor(img)
            ttttfff = torch.Tensor([1])
            # print(0000000000000000)
            # print(input1.shape)
            # imgg =imgg.resize((1,3,218,178))

            # image = Variable(torch.unsqueeze(image, dim=0).float(), requires_grad=False)
            # imggf = Variable(torch.unsqueeze(th.FloatTensor(r), dim=0).float(), requires_grad=False)
            # cv2.imshow("windows_name", np.uint8(imggf.cpu().numpy()))
            # cv2.waitKey()
            # print(imggf)
            # image = image
            # return label ,image ,target
            # print(img.shape)
            # tesyt = np.uint8(imggf.cpu().numpy())
        else:
            acc = torch.rand([ 3, 218, 178]) * 255
            acc = torch.round(acc)
            input1 = acc
            ttttfff = torch.Tensor([0])
            # print(1111111111111111)

        # return input1,ttttfff
        return input1,
        # return  image, target


aaa =dataset2(r'K:\aaaaa\Img\img_align_celeba')
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger
logger = TensorBoardLogger('tb_logs', name='my_model')
trainer = pyl.Trainer(gpus=1,logger =logger)


trainer.fit(model=main_modle(),train_dataloader=DataLoader(aaa,shuffle=True,batch_size=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace sigmoid activation function with tanh. Sigmoid goes to 0 when D is very confident

Comment: but  tanh will send negative number it well lead to   RuntimeError: all elements of input should be between 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

You should train Discriminator and Generator in turns for stability purposes. I would suggest trying to train Generator first without updating discriminator parameters to observe whether it is capable of training or is something wrong with the implementation. Also, I could suggest adding regularization term.

Comment: train Discriminator and Generator in turns i do it so i add this if optimizer_idx == 1: i use tow optimizer but when i train it i can see Discriminator loss to be low but Generator nothing to learn